# How to pass a parameter to another class using events

Tags: c#, events, parameters, delegates

I have a `usercontrol` which is having one button

**Usercontrolclass.cs**

Button click event

```
  private void btn_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            value= Convert.ToDouble(txt_ActualValue.Text);

            if(getvalue!=null)
            getvalue(null, new EventArga());
        }
```

private variable

```
private int value;
```

property:

```
 public double finalvalue
        {
            get
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
```

**MainForm.cs**

> I'm using that Usercontrol into this mainform

I need to get the value from this class

in constructor:

```
Usercontrolclass.getvalue+=Usercontrolclass_getvalue;
```

in method:

```
 private void   UserControlclass_getvalue()
    {
      here I need to get the "value";

     int myval = Usercontrolclass.finalvalue;  // I can get like this
    }
```

my question is without using properties simply pass a parameter into the event arguments and get the value in to  the mainfrom?

```
  if(getvalue!=null)
                getvalue(null, new EventArga(value));
```

Because I don't allowed to do like this **`classname.properties`**

as well as don't allowed to pass a parameter using method like this

in Usercontrol class

```
 Mainform obj = new Mainform ();
            obj.getvalue(value);
```

Is there any other way to do this? I mean pass a variable to another class by using events?

Comment: you can make your own delegate event and trigger it when the button is called, you can then actually add an event listener on your usercontroll in your main. Ill make a quick example hold on

Comment: Thank you. I am waiting @EpicKip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your own `events`, you can fire them from the `usercontrol` (here is where the event takes place) and put a listener on your main form.

**User control:**

```
//You custom event, has to be inside namespace but outside class
public delegate void MyCustomEvent(int value);

public partial class aUserControl : UserControl
{
    //Here you initialize it
    public event MyCustomEvent CustomEvent;

    public aUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void theButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        CustomEvent?.Invoke(5);//using magic number for test
        //You can call this anywhere in the user control to fire the event
    }
}
```

Now in the main form I added the usercontrol and an event listener

**Main form:**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Here you add the event listener to your user control
    aUserControl1.CustomEvent += AUserControl1_CustomEvent;
}

private void AUserControl1_CustomEvent( int value )
{
    MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
    //This is the Main form and I now have the value here 
    //whenever the button is clicked (or event is fired from somewhere else)
}
```

Comment: Just give me a sec .. I will check it out now

Comment: That's really awesome!!. Its working exactly what I want... Its like a magic!! :). its make me, Like to learn more about delegates and events . thank you very much

Comment: @user688 Alright great :) you can do some awesome stuff with them so I encourage you to do so!